# In Team Foundation Server, is it possible to customize the display order of items in a dropdown list, for a work item template?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm using Team Foundation Server 2015, and am trying to customize the process template to more closely match our team's process.

I already have Team Foundation Server power tools installed, and am able to use the Process Editor to import / export the templates for the work item types.

I would like to modify the User Story template, and change the order of the items in the State drop down list. (They are, by default, sorted alphabetically.)

The fields are currently sorted like this:

- Active
- Closed
- New
- Removed
- Resolved

I would like them to be sorted like this (which matches the order that the states should transition to):

- New
- Active
- Resolved
- Closed
- Removed

Answer (score 2):

No, this doesn't seem to be possible.

If you look at the [Process customization workflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms194981.aspx) it states:

*Regardless of the sequence in which you define the states, they are listed in alphanumeric order in the drop-down menu for the State field.*